# Insert user provided values in database using flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to insert some values in an existing table (clients) in a database (master) in a Flask application. The idea is to insert values provided by the user or some script (Stored in a variable)

My flask script is a follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://user:pswd@localhost/master'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class clients():
    __tablename__ = "clients"
    def __init__(self, client_id, command, response, log_date):
        client_id = 'asdfg123'
        command = 'echo'
        response = 'All Is Well'
        log_date = '2018-06-21'

db.session.commit()

print "yo"

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return 'Hello World !'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The database schema is as follows:

```
master=> select * from clients;
 client_id | command |     response     |  log_date  
-----------+---------+------------------+------------
 QWERTY123 | ls      | OK Report Hai Ji | 2018-06-21
(1 row)
```

Near about all the documents/examples talk about creating the schema and then using self to insert values, which is useless for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there seems to be a few things missing from this to make it work.  Firstly the definition of your model needs a few things.

Here is what I think it should be.

```
class Client(db.Model):
  client_id = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True)
  command = db.Column(db.String(30))
  response = db.Column(db.String(30))
  log_date = db.Column(db.Date)
```

This model then represents a single row in your table. Then within one of your routes you can pull user data from a form POST or from a path variable or something and create an object like so.

```
client = Client(client_id=formvar1, command=formvar2, response=formvar3, log_date=formvar4)
```

Now you have the object you want to tell SQLAlchemy (still in the route) to insert this object into the database.

```
db.session.add(client)
db.session.commit()
```